Solnet deriving PDA from programId and marketId
When attempting to replicate the following code with Solnet and C#
 static getAssociatedAuthority({ programId, marketId }: { programId: PublicKey; marketId: PublicKey }) {
    const seeds = [marketId.toBuffer()]

    let nonce = 0
    let publicKey: PublicKey

    while (nonce < 100) {
      try {
        const seedsWithNonce = seeds.concat(Buffer.from([nonce]), Buffer.alloc(7))
        publicKey = PublicKey.createProgramAddressSync(seedsWithNonce, programId)
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof TypeError) {
          throw err
        }
        nonce++
        continue
      }
      return { publicKey, nonce }
    }

    return logger.throwArgumentError('unable to find a viable program address nonce', 'params', {
      programId,
      marketId,
    })
  }
}

I end up with something that looks like this
var seeds = marketId.ToBuffer();
ulong nonce = 0;
while (nonce < 100)
{
    try
    {
        //Buffer.alloc(7) nonce u64
        var seedsWithNonce = seeds.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(nonce)).Concat(new byte[7]);
        IEnumerable<byte[]> seedNonce = new List<byte[]>() { seedsWithNonce.ToArray() };
        var publicKey = ProgramAddress.CreateProgramAddressSync(seedNonce, programId);
        return publicKey;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is ArgumentException || ex is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        nonce++;
    }

However, im unsure how to replicate the
 const seeds = [marketId.toBuffer()]
Any usefull insights would be highly appriciated.
Every attempt ive done so far, results in the seed being atleast 32 bytes(that would be the publicKeyBytes of the marketId)

Solved it.
var seedNonce = new List<byte[]>
{
    marketId.KeyBytes,
    BitConverter.GetBytes(signerSeed)
};
if (PublicKey.TryCreateProgramAddress(seedNonce, programId, out var key))
{
    return key;
}
return null;

was the correct solution
